# Add arguments one by one to a delegate then execute it

Tags: c#, exception, delegates, delayed-execution

Yesterday I wanted to create an `ExceptionHandler` class to which for example we could pass:

- the exception
- the method where that happened
- the parameters given to that method

The `ExceptionHandler` would implement a custom business logic and re-execute automatically (or not) the method with the same parameters.

[The closest solution I found](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/164917/Pass-a-method-with-N-params-as-parameter-in-C#answer1) was by using a `delegate` like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvokeMyMethod(Test, "string", 1);
    InvokeMyMethod(TestN, "other string", 3, Color.Red);
}

public delegate void MyMethodDelegate(params object[] args);

public void InvokeMyMethod(MyMethodDelegate method, params object[] args)
{
    method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}

public void Test(params object[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2) return;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}{1}", args[0], args[1]));
}

public void TestN(params object[] args)
{
    // or, whatewer
    if (args.Length < 3) return;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", args[0], args[1], args[2]));
}
```

However this solution is still not perfect because of the methods' signature. I don't want all my methods receive a unique parameter `params object[] args`, moreover this is often not possible directly for example with all UI related events (Winform, ASP.NET, WPF or whatever).

So I'd like to know if there is a way to pass one by one arguments to a delegate and then execute the function only when we are ready?

For example here is an imaginary code with non-existing methods `AddArgument` and `Execute`

```
public void InvokeMyMethod(MyMethodDelegate method, params object[] args)
{
    foreach(var arg in args)
    {
        method.AddArgument(arg);
    }
    method.Execute();
}
```

By this way all our functions could keep their original signature and receive multiple arguments instead of an array.

Comment: Sounds like the "builder" pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: Hum ok I didn't know the name of this pattern and how to search it on Google. I will read about this. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code isn't far off at all.  You can get rid of requiring all the called methods have the same signature as long as you make InvokeMyMethod just take the abstract Delegate class and you explicitly specify the delegate type when you call the function (it won't infer the type).  We can take advantage of the fact that there are generic delegate types in C# so we don't need to declare every possible set of method signatures that we want to use.

If you wanted to call functions with a return value you'd need to use `Func<>` in place of `Action<>`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvokeMyMethod((Action<string,int>) Test, "string", 1);
    InvokeMyMethod((Action<string,int,Color>) TestN, "other string", 3, Color.Red);
}

public void InvokeMyMethod(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}

public void Test(string s, int i)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}{1}", s, i));
}

public void TestN(string s, int i, Color c)
{
    // or, whatewer
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", s, i , c);
}
```

Comment: I know I just copy pasted the original code from the source. But that doesn't answer to the question. I'm blocked because `DynamicInvoke` is waiting for a single parameter of type `object[]` instead of being able to accept an unknown number of parameters as described in my imaginary code example

Comment: @JérômeMével Ah, sorry, now I see what you were asking.  Gave some more helpful code for you.